# Winform Combobox Changing GUI with vaules

Tags: winforms, combobox

I am trying to make a booking system in winforms. And i have a combobox where you can select the numbers from one to ten. I also have 10 groupboxes, and i only want the amount of group boxes shown that equals to the selected number in the combobox. In the group boxes i have another combobox where i can select the seat number thats why its important that not all the boxes are shown at the same time. I am kind of lost i have tried to use an actionlistener but i did not succed.

Here i call the GUI where the combobox is found in:

```
private void btnMakeBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReferenceBooking.BookingServiceClient bookingService = new ServiceReferenceBooking.BookingServiceClient();
        ServiceReferenceTickets.TicketsServiceClient ticketsService = new ServiceReferenceTickets.TicketsServiceClient();
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        InitializeMakeBookingComponents();

        var allBookings = bookingService.GetAllBookings();
        dataGridView2.DataSource = allBookings;

        cbTickets.ValueMember = "amount";
        cbTickets.DisplayMember = "amount";
        cbTickets.DataSource = ticketsService.GetAllTickets();

    }
```

And here is the Event that i am trying to make:

```
private void cbTickets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbTickets.SelectedItem.ToString() == "2")
            {
                gboxSeat2.Visible = true;
            }   
    }
```

I get the error: object reference not set to an instance of an object.
and it is on the line where the if statement is.

this is the event that i have tried to create but the GroupBox is not getting visible when selecting 2.

Hope you guys can help! thanks

Comment: Where you got struck? What is the problem, post your code if something isn't working in that. Sounds like just a matter of setting the `GroupBox.Visible` property in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of that numbers combobox.

Comment: I dont have any code to post. Yes that was what i was thinking of doing. I have set all GroupBox.Visible = false so that by default non of them is shown. But i dont know how to use the SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: That's rather [simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try something, come here if you run into a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` the first is the 0 based index of the item that was selected the second is the actual item which is what you are looking for.  Try this

```
private void cbTickets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem == "2")        
    {
        gboxSeat2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

---

To flesh out my suggestion:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declare your basic controls here
    GroupBox gboxSeat1 = new GroupBox() { BackColor = Color.Red, Visible=false};
    GroupBox gboxSeat2 = new GroupBox() { BackColor = Color.Blue, Visible = false };
    GroupBox gboxSeat3 = new GroupBox() { BackColor = Color.Green, Visible = false };
    GroupBox gboxSeat4 = new GroupBox() { BackColor = Color.Orange, Visible = false };
    ComboBox cbTickets = new ComboBox() { Items = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" }, Height = 35, Width = 150 };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Setup handlers and add them to the panel
        cbTickets.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
        panel1.Controls.Add(gboxSeat1);
        panel1.Controls.Add(gboxSeat2);
        panel1.Controls.Add(gboxSeat3);
        panel1.Controls.Add(gboxSeat4);
        panel1.Controls.Add(cbTickets);

    }

    private void InitializeBookingComponents()
    {
        //Arrange your controls the way you want here
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem == "2")
            gboxSeat2.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

This will make sure you only ever have one control, you can remove or add them to your panel at your leisure maintaining only one of your controls

Comment: I have tried this, and now i get an error that says: object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do you know why this might be ? it somehow gets a null value. I dont understand why ?

Comment: Show the exact code that you are using that gives that error. It is saying that one of your objects is null

Comment: Okay i am going to edit the code above. Just a moment.

Comment: put a breakpoint on your If statement and check your variables to see what is null.

Comment: my cbTickets.SelectedItem is null ?

Comment: I also made a change to my answer so that it is using the sender from the event to get the Combobox Item.

Comment: no errors now. But the Groupbox does not show. And i can see in the debugger that it has gotten a value when i change the index

Comment: What that is telling me is that cbTicket was null. try using a breakpoint and stepping through your If statement making sure it is getting to the line to make the groupbox visible.

Comment: When i step in to the if statement it keeps saying that Visible = false. For some reason

Comment: Try doing a build it sounds like your source code is out of sync with your program. You should be getting an error if your GroupBox wasn't accessible. Are you using threading or seperate forms?

Comment: i have tried to build it again and it dosent seem to changes it. No i am only using one Form but i refresh the a oanl where all the components is placed every time i click a new item in the menu. And when i do this i call the InitializeMakeBookingComponents(); and so on for each menu item

Comment: Try commenting out that line and the panel.clear line before it and see what happens

Comment: Then i get the same error as before. It is like the event never fires ?

Comment: This only a guess since I don't know what your InitializeMakeBookingComponents() is doing, but if it is creating new controls when it is clicked after clearing the old controls off of the panel, the old controls are not disposed of causing you to have multiple objects.  I would probably make my controls  class level objects and add/remove/position them as necessary that way they are always there.  In thinking about what you said about your GroupBox visible staying false, it will if it is not assigned to a container or its container's visibility is false.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what InitializeMakeBookingComponents() is doing. I dont understand fully how you would do that?

Comment: Just added some code to explain what I was suggesting

Comment: Tried to do what you suggestet. I dosent seem to work. I have tried to make a new Groupbox for testing. And i look like the event dont fire for some reason

Comment: That was just a concept to give you an idea how to not keep recreating your control, you will need to create a small test project and try to implement your basic application functionality and build from there. you should only need to create a control once, you can add/remove, disable/enable, hide, make visible and place it as you wish. You just need to make sure that they are created with class level scope.